# Problem with LaTeX hyperref

Tags: encoding, latex, package, hyperref

i have an url with cyrilic characters:

```
http://www.pravoslavie.bg/Възпитание/Духовно-и-светско-образование
```

when i compile the document, i get following as url:

```
http://www.pravoslavie.bg/%5CT2A%5CCYRV%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrhrdsn%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrz%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrp%20%5CT2A%5Ccyri%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrt%20%5CT2A%5Ccyra%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrn%20%5CT2A%5Ccyri%20%5CT2A%5Ccyre%20/%5CT2A%5CCYRD%20%5CT2A%5Ccyru%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrh%20%5CT2A%5Ccyro%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrv%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrn%20%5CT2A%5Ccyro%20-%5CT2A%5Ccyri%20-%5CT2A%5Ccyrs%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrv%20%5CT2A%5Ccyre%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrt%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrs%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrk%20%5CT2A%5Ccyro%20-%5CT2A%5Ccyro%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrb%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrr%20%5CT2A%5Ccyra%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrz%20%5CT2A%5Ccyro%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrv%20%5CT2A%5Ccyra%20%5CT2A%5Ccyrn%20%5CT2A%5Ccyri%20%5CT2A%5Ccyre
```

and that ist not the same. Can I set the encoding to utf8 for hyperref? Or how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mike Weller:
i have already \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} in my document, with utf8x i get following as url:

```
http://www.pravoslavie.bg/\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð·}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð¿}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð ̧}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð°}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð1⁄2}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð ̧}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\relax\
endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ðμ}intopreamble]/\begingroup\let\relax\
relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\
relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\
relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\
relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð3⁄4}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\
relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð2}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\
relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð1⁄2}intopreamble]\begingroup\let\relax\
relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð3⁄4}intopreamble]-\begingroup\let\
relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð ̧}intopreamble]-\begingroup\
let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]\begingroup\
let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð2}intopreamble]\begingroup\
let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ðμ}intopreamble]\begingroup\
let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]\begingroup\
let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]\begingroup\
let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ðo}intopreamble]\begingroup\
let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð3⁄4}intopreamble]-\
begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð3⁄4}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð±}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ñ}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð°}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð·}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð3⁄4}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð2}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð°}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð1⁄2}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ð ̧}intopreamble]
\begingroup\let\relax\relax\endgroup[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ðμ}intopreamble]D
```

edit: the problem is solved - i've used URL Encoding to convert the cyrilic chars :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy not to use the `\url` command (i.e., you'll need to break lines manually) you can do the following in regular LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{http://www.pravoslavie.bg/Възпитание/Духовно-и-светско-образование}
\end{document}
```

If you need to get the hyperlinks working, my only suggestion for now is to use either XeTeX or LuaTeX to be able to use proper unicode input/output. Something like the following produces at least the correct-looking output in XeTeX, although the hyperlink itself is broken for some reason `:(`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,hyperref}
\setmonofont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}
\url{http://www.pravoslavie.bg/Възпитание/Духовно-и-светско-образование}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the pdftitle field.

splitting use declaration and setup made it work correctly

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdftitle=Priorità
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your LaTeX source is utf8 encoded, try adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to your document. If utf8 doesn't work try utf8x. See [here](http://termos.vemod.net/how-to-use-utf-8-encoding-with-latex)

Comment: I'm not sure, but does exist cyrilic `babel` package? I would also try \texttt{adress} there if `url` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If it *is*, as the other posters seem to assume, a charset issue, make sure the character encoding for the bibtex source and the tex document match.  Cf. [Q#1635788: Different encoding of latex and bibtex files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635788/different-encoding-of-latex-and-bibtex-files).  You don't *need* to make the character encodings both be utf8; is should think that latin-5 or KOI8-R would both work, but it is the best supported.

If it isn't, than as per my comment above: look at the software chain that you are using: editor, makefiles, &c, to see if something is doing unwanted URL escaping for you.  Then deal ruthlessly with the offending software.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
```

worked for me (since at least June 2010) using texlive distribution
(not sure if it is relevant).